# Variables in typescript projects returns 'any' for Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to use Firebase Cloud Functions with Typescript rather than Javascript. One thing is bothering me: my IDE is not autocompleting me for every Typescript files like it does on Javascript files. This is what I mean:

Typescript file:
[image]

Javascript file:
[image]

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

It autocompletes every function nicely on .js files, but not on .ts files. I did have chosen Typescript as my language. This happens on every IDE I try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using TypeScript, you should use `import` statements instead of `require`.  Try these lines instead:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions"
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"
```

When you use these, you'll find is that `functions` and `admin` will give you autocomplete options under their namespace when you type `.` after those identifiers.